# How Eclipse display Errors/Warnings in preference page?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

How Eclipse display Errors/Warnings in preference page

> Preferences -> compiler -> Errors/Warnings

When user open this page for the first time, Is it displayed from any .properties/.prefs file or Is it hard coded?

What actually happens when we click on "Restore Defaults"?(will it display hard coded values or will it take from any file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default values for this are set by the `org.eclipse.jdt.ui` plugin using the preference initializer class `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaCorePreferenceInitializer` defined using the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.preferences` extension point.

So this can't really be modified.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please let me know the values comes from **JavaCorePreferenceInitializer** are hard coded or taking it from any .properties file.?